# Creating an image view with other image view tag

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ipad, tags, uiimageview

In my app i have a condition in which I have to initialize a image view in my class with the same tag as other image view. So can anyone tell me how to create an image view with tag of other image view? I wrote the code like this but not getting the result:

```
UIImageView *imageView2=[imageView viewWithTag:i];
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, Christina. I’ve noticed you’ve been using the ‘cocoa’ tag in your questions about Cocoa Touch. The ‘cocoa’ tag is for Cocoa on Mac OS X; you should use the ‘cocoa-touch’ tag instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
UIImageView *imageView1 = [view viewWithTag:i];
```

Create your second image view with the tag of your first image view .

```
UIImageView * imageView2= [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,20,width,height)];
imageView2.tag = imageView1.tag;
```